# Why is a special signal handler necessary for asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#unix-signals), I need to use `loop.add_signal_handler()` to register a signal handler to interact with the event loop.

> Unlike signal handlers registered using `signal.signal()`, a callback
>   registered with this function is allowed to interact with the event
>   loop.

Why is this necessary? What is wrong about using the normal `signal.signal()` to register signals with `asyncio`?

Comment: What's "the normal way"?

Comment: @pylang signal.signal()

Comment: Reading from the doc, `signal.signal` is for blocking functions. It doesn't register the handler to main loop, thus breaking the async patterns. And it doesn't register an `async` function. For a typical async app all functions should be `async` and be handled in the event loop.

Comment: @knh190 The handler not being awaitable is not a deal-breaker because the handler can always use `asyncio.create_task()` to launch a coroutine. (The same goes for `add_signal_handler`.) The real problem is that the handler invoked by `signal.signal` may be invoked while the event loop is doing internal bookkeeping, or even in a totally different thread (if the event loop runs outside the main thread). `add_signal_handler` is designed to prevent such reentrance and invoke the callback along with other event loop callbacks, such as those scheduled with `call_soon`.